# How to make synchronous network call in android?

Tags: android

I am trying to make an application that constantly hits the google API to fetch the distance between two points and then process the distance and add it in db inside a loop.

I was previously using the volley but it does not waits and my function proceeds with the rest of lines of code. I need help so that the line of code waits for that method to return only if some result is received once I hit google API, then use that result in next line of code.

Comment: maybe you can make use of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android) instead

Comment: **Synchronous network call are not encouraged.**

Comment: Volley can do that,just create a call back interface and implement it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do synchronous calls on the main thread. Blocking the UI thread on a network call for more than a specified period of time would trigger an ANR.

A couple of options would be to use an [AysncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) or AsyncTaskLoader. Blocking the main thread is definitely not recommended.

AsyncTasks create a separate thread of execution while the UI thread can continue with its work.

Android applications usually start with a single thread of execution so if you block this thread then an ANR would result.

Take a look [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr)

If you don't mind the ANRs which will not be acceptable to a user then go with using a simple HttpURLConnection but this is not recommended.

If you do not prefer the AsyncTask approach you can create a Runnable to do the background processing and then update the UI thread.

More [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads)

Comment: you can use a coroutine and await for completion on the main thread

Comment: and how does that prevent an ANR?

Comment: the actual request is made on a separate thread, main thread is just waiting for response.

Comment: that's what I've mentioned in my answer.

Comment: asynctasks are already obsolete constructs, such things should be used only on projects where kotlin is not an option

Comment: Asynctasks are not obsolete in Android and can be used be it Java or Kotlin. Get your facts straight.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking into coroutines. More specifically take a look at the  `async` launcher which should return the value to an awaiting variable. Your code runs asynchronously (starting a new thread so your main UI thread doesn't block and the user can freely do as they wish) and when the call returns your code is called once again at the point where the variable will be awaiting. You could set a timer right before starting the async call and stop it after await.

You could also use withContext{} to await for a result. The code will be continued in the calling function when the coroutine returns a result.

```
startTimer()
val job = coroutineScope{
    async{
        networkCall()
    }
}
job.await()
stopTimer()
```

or

```
startTimer()
coroutineScope{
    launch{
        withContext{
            networkCall()
        }
        //code will continue when networkCall() has returned a result
        stopTimer() //be careful, this may be called through a background thread.
    }
}
```

Coroutines are thread-safe and lightweight so you can start as many as you want without any problems. Also, by using `coroutineScope` you will avoid lifecycle problems like your ui being rotated which would normally cause a network call to be resent. With `coroutineScope` your call will have the life span of the calling activity/fragment thus it will be cancelled or killed if your app unexpectedly decides to stop and not care for the result any longer.

Hope this helped, Panos.

Comment: Corountines are Kotlin specific.

Answer (score 0):

If you are beginner use retrofit library to make API calls in there is option `enque` will call API background for you.

https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial

If you are pro go for Rxjava with Retrofit.
https://medium.com/3xplore/handling-api-calls-using-retrofit-2-and-rxjava-2-1871c891b6ae

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a jobservice to get distance in an interval.You can view the implementation .[here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobService)